# Subversion auto-props - automatically overwrite

Tags: svn

I try to find out how I can tell subversion to automatically overwrite all my PDF files with the revision from the server without asking me....

Does anybody can help me on this topic?

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: Where all your PDF files located? What you are trying to do? How you are trying? Please give some more clarity.

Comment: Imagine a "ordinary" svn repository holding several files and also some PDFs.
When I do a svn update I want to automatically overwrite my local PDFs with them from the SVN server without asking me if I want to keep my local file... 
All other files should be handled in the common way by asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svn update --accept theirs-full` which will always overwrite your working copy files with the files from repository in case of conflicts. However if you want to do for non-conflicting files also, then first you have to do `svn revert` which will revert all your local changes. Then you can use `svn update`